# Return Substring ONLY from MySQL

Tags: mysql, substring

I need to figure out a way to only return image URLs from a large, multi-paragraph record. I have an id (int) and a body (text) column. So my results need to look like this:

```
id | body
---------------------
#  | http://... .jpg
```

Returning the " and the src= is fine, if that's what's needed. There are more than one image per page, and I need all of them, ideally on separate lines.

I can't seem to wrap my head around this, as every combination of SELECT I can find gives me back the **entire** record. I don't need 2,000 words of content - I just need the URLs.

Any ideas, O Great Community of Wiser Than I People?

Comment: This is going to be _really_ hard with MySQL alone. You are much better off pulling the entire record, then parsing it with a proper HTML parser (assuming this is HTML, since you mentioned `src=`), since MySQL has native support only for matching the presence of a regular expression, not extraction...

Comment: use substring and find the start of http:// and the start of .jpg to find start/ends.  Alternatively use Regular Expressions.

Comment: Regular expression can't be used in MySQL. It will only return 0 or 1, so a match regex is possible, a return regex not.

Comment: Figured as much. Thank for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion is, that if you need to retrieve portions of the overall data like that, then you should make modifications to your DB schema to store information in that manner.  Perhaps put together a script to go through the database and populate a new field which contains only the links.

Outside of that, you can investigate MySQL's string functions  (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html) to come up with a solution that might work for you.  I might suggest looking at SUBSTRING_INDEX (based on `src="`).  But the reality is that MySQL's functionality is pretty limited for doing something like you suggest, especially if you have multiple URL's from any given content block you need to extract. If you need to do it regularly in your app, then you would be best served by splitting this information into a separate field.

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE as
(Select UPPER('HELLO THIS IS A TEST OF THE EMERGENCY 
 HTTP://someurl.domain.gov/wizziwig.jpg and more next and still more text.') 
 as txt
FROM DUAL)
select instr(txt,'HTTP:'), instr(txt,'.JPG'), 
      substr(txt,instr(txt,'HTTP:'),instr(txt,'.JPG')
      -instr(txt,'HTTP:')+4) from CTE
```

However this has limits on it assumes that there is only ONE HTTP:/ and only one .JPG

Comment: Thanks. But there are two, sometimes three per page. :|